# Error Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 with FCM in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, cocoapods

I am getting this error while adding FCM in my app via Cocoa pods. FCM is the Firebase cloud messaging SDK from the google.

I have tried to removing arm64 from target of project and pod project.
And setting build for architecture only yes/no both.

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRInstanceID", referenced from:
>         type metadata accessor for __ObjC.FIRInstanceID in AppDelegate.o
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRMessaging", referenced from:
>         type metadata accessor for __ObjC.FIRMessaging in AppDelegate.o
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRApp", referenced from:
>         type metadata accessor for __ObjC.FIRApp in AppDelegate.o
>     "_kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification", referenced from:
>         Memorymail.AppDelegate.configNotificationSettings (Memorymail.AppDelegate)() -> () in AppDelegate.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Has anyone solution for this?

Comment: Did you install the pods? Did you build from the workspace and not the project?

Comment: Yes, now it is solved.

Comment: @GopalDevra, could you explain what did you do for this thing to work?

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced same cases.
I resolved it by adding **GoogleService-Info.plist** to project.
(I downloaded it from firebase console.)